# Controlling Tomcat starting issue with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am trying to start Tomcat 7.0.55 from Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 14.04.

It is working perfectly fine when the Eclipse is run through `sudo nautilus`.
But when the Eclipse is used via normal user and Tomcat is started, the following 
error occurs:

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

I have tried to increase the timeouts to 200 seconds, but still the same error.

Till the time Eclipse tries to start the Tomcat, the server tab shows following status

> Tomcat 7.0 Server at localhost [ Starting, Synchronized]

and the console tab shows:

```
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testprj' did not find a matching property.
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1168 ms
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 17, 2014 3:02:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1131 ms
```

and once the error pops, the Eclipse server tab shows:

> Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost [ Stopped, Synchronized]

Any help ?

Comment: If you don't have tomcat plugin for eclipse, you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9714221/2231632 - sounds awfully similar to your issue.

Comment: its not the issue of plugin. The solution mentioned in the link was already tested, but no success.

Comment: And did you delete the tomcat config (including the runtime) and recreate it again as normal user to see if it's a matter of bad config or missing config updates or some file permissions may be?

Comment: even if i am running the eclipse via terminal, it is working fine.